# Open/Configure/Toggle FRDM-KL46Z GPIO Register to Light Up External LED/Resistor

Tags: c, arm, embedded, gpio, mbed

Board: FRDM-KL46Z
Red generic LED
820ohm resistor (which is the correct resistor for this LED)
Breadboard used to connect from port pin 1 of j4 io header (io header pin 4) to LED in series with one resistor and terminating in ground.

I am attempting to execute some test code to light up an LED/resistor in series. I was given this generic test code to start but there seems to be something missing.

```
int main()
{

SIM_BASE_PTR->SCGC5 = 1 << SIM_SCGC5_PORTB_SHIFT;
PORTB_PCR1 |= PORT_PCR_MUX(0b001);
PTB_BASE_PTR->PDDR |= 1 << 1;
PTB_BASE_PTR->PDOR |= 1 << 1;

return 0;
}
```

Regardless of the LED configuration, I am not getting any voltage out of the pin when checking it with a digital multi-meter.

Comment: `PDOR &= 1 << 1;` won't bring PTB1 high. `PDOR |= (1 << 1);` will.

Comment: Updated! Still no luck on the multi-meter either with the change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see there are two problems:

1. The chosen resistor's value is too big. Try 330 ohm instead.
2. If the connection is ended with ground, you should bring PTB3 high, not low.

   ```
   PTB_BASE_PTR->PDOR |= (1<<3);
   ```
3. PTB3 (A3 in Arduino numeration) in your board is J4 header pin **8** as seen on https://mcuoneclipse.files.wordpress.com/2013/08/frdm-kl46z-back-side.png.

Comment: Peter, the resistor value given cannot be changed unfortunately, I have tried to bring PTB3 high and low. Neither have worked :/ Is there any other information I could provide to get more assistance with this? I have been trying to get this to work for 3 days now sadly.

Comment: I tried switching the connection to pin 8 physically and it still did not function, I tried to move it back to the original pin (IO header pin 4) and change the code to pin 1. Still no luck. I have tried many combinations of numbers, I think somehow I am missing a command or line of code?!

Comment: WELL GUESS WHAT! I got a new circuit board and found out that mine is defective, the pins are not functioning on my board. I used a friend's board and pushed my EXACT SAME CODE to it and it worked fine.

Thanks Peter, you are completely correct here.

Comment: @mar10 Yeah, the behaviour you described was strange. Glad that I helped somehow.

Comment: The resistor value is quite well for a low-current LED, 330R would be too low. OP does not state which type it is (not sure what he means with "generic LED", but as the resistor cannot be changed (why? cannot solder?) OP can use such an LED). Even if not, it should light up quite a bit (red LEDs are more sensitive than other colors).